# What kind of oak are these acorns from?

Tags: identification, trees, oak

[image]

Can anyone identify the oak species these acorns come from?

Here are some pics of the leaves and bark

[image: leaves and bark]

[image: trunk]

Comment: Your profile says you're in Ireland. Were these acorns also found in Ireland? Anything else you can tell us about the tree they came from or where it was growing?

Comment: Yeah this was in Ireland in the Phoenix Park. I did have a leaf but my daughter threw it away. Was just thinking of planting them really to see if they will grow

Comment: From what I remember of the leaf it had finger-shaped leaves if you know what I mean.

Comment: @conorgriffin please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks, next time I'm at the park I'll get some leaves and maybe update the question but it sounds like you're right

Comment: You HAVE to add a couple of leaves or a bud and the entire tree for form.  Oh well, if you go back please collect a few more leaves!  Bamboo is the best ID'er on this site with at least 4 or 5 others far better than mesef.

Comment: Turkey Oak (Quercus cerris)- the fissured, grey bark is typical...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only a limited number of Oaks which produce this mossy cap at the bottom of the acorn - those that do are listed below, but without leaves, it's next to impossible to be certain which it might be:-

[Quercus suber](https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/quercus-suber), maybe, the Cork Oak;

Or [Quercus cerris](http://www.gardenaction.co.uk/trees/quercus/quercus-cerris-turkey-oak.asp) (Turkey Oak, known as European Turkey Oak in countries outside of Europe);

And possibly Quercus hispanica 'Lucombeana' - can't find an accessible online image of this one's acorns, though there is one in my tree directory. Roger's Trees and Shrubs has a good picture, but their site is down currently.

Of these, Turkey Oak is widespread in the UK and Eire, and is the most likely candidate.

UPDATE - The images you've added, particularly of the grey, fissured/ridged bark, confirm the ID as Quercus cerris (Turkey Oak).

Answer (score 0):

My guess without the leaves or bark would be Quercus robur; the English Oak or the Common Oak or the pendunculate oak.[Quercus robur](https://www.google.com/search?q=quercus%20robur&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=481&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjZob_68s_PAhXCKGMKHVtMDjwQiR4IhwEhttp://)

Comment: Nope. The caps of q. robur are not fuzzy like these.

Comment: From what I've seen, yes they are.  Did you look at the pictures I sent? Hey, I am quite often wrong!!

Comment: Sigh, I think Bamboo's Turkey oak is closest.  Maybe I was looking at a hybrid but of course can't find those pictures.  Oh I love being wrong.  Keeps me brutally humble.

Comment: I spent half my childhood in the branches of a q. r. - three trees in my parents' garden and *lots* in the forest nearby. And the acorns make excellent playing / crafting material. The caps don't have those "tendrils".

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I've already conceded I was wrong, again...you don't have to convince me any further!  Grins!  This is such a great way to keep our knowledge up to date and correct, huh!